# I want my images to full on desktop mode and also full on mobile mode

Tags: html, css, image

I made a function to give random images on reload but in mobile mode its not fitting to screen and only giving half of the image here's some code:
css:
/* BG */

```
  #bg {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  #bg:before,
  #bg:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #bg:before {
    -moz-transition: background-color 2.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 2.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 2.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.75s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.75s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.75s;
    transition-delay: 0.75s;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to top,
        rgba(19, 21, 25, 0.5),
        rgba(19, 21, 25, 0.5)
      ),
      url("../../images/overlay.png");
    background-size: auto, 256px 256px;
    background-position: center, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  #bg:after {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.125);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.125);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.125);
    transform: scale(1.125);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.325s ease-in-out,
      -moz-filter 0.325s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.325s ease-in-out,
      -webkit-filter 0.325s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.325s ease-in-out,
      -ms-filter 0.325s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.325s ease-in-out, filter 0.325s ease-in-out;
    background-image: url("https://pic.re/image");
    /* ../../images/bg.jpg */
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  body.is-article-visible #bg:after {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0825);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0825);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0825);
    transform: scale(1.0825);
    -moz-filter: blur(0.2rem);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0.2rem);
    -ms-filter: blur(0.2rem);
    filter: blur(0.2rem);
  }

  body.is-preload #bg:before {
    background-color: #000000;
  }
```

html:

I am making an API. I made a function to give random images on reload but I want my image to fit to screen accordingly. If user using it on desktop it will give fit screen images as well to mobile screen.

Comment: html: <div id="bg"></div>

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).